# How to resize UITableView width to fit its content?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

Is there possible way to adjust table view width by width of biggest text that should be set in the cellTitle label?

iOS 8 , SWIFT

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? do you want to put some other controls right to the tableview? or why shouldn't it take up the whole screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Set a `width` auto-layout constraint to the table view.
2. Set an `outlet` from the constraint to your code (ctrl+drag, just like a view).
3. When you have the size of the label (if the label also has auto-layout then you will have it at `viewDidLayoutSubviews`) set the width to the table like so:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
       self.myTableWidthConstraint.constant = self.myLabel.frame.size.width;  
       [self.myTableView updateConstraints];  
       [self.myTableView layoutIfNeeded];
   }
   ```

Comment: Glad it worked, if the answer solved your problem please consider marking the green check for the answer, thanks (:

Answer (score 4):

```
public override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    // Set the popover tableview width to be max compressed size (assumes all cells visible)
    let maxWidth = tableView.visibleCells.reduce(0.0) { (currentMax, cell) -> CGFloat in
        return max(currentMax, cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).width)
    }

    var contentSize = tableView.contentSize
    contentSize.width = maxWidth
    tableView.contentSize = contentSize
    tableView.bounds.size = contentSize
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to do that in the size inspector.